# RabbitMQ Message size limitiation?

Tags: debugging, rabbitmq

I am trying to gauge the performance of RabbitMQ when my message size increases to a few MB. However, even when I sent a 32KB message, I get a `Resource temporarily unavilable` message from the Server. There's no error in the log files, there are no memory limit reaching errors... How do I go about debugging this issue?

If it's on any help, I'm running this on EC2 T1.micro instance.. So 592MB RAM.

Comment: It's unclear how do you get this message, which client library do you use, did you meet [Flow Control](http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html) limits, what does management panel shows.

Comment: Apologies.. I use `rabbitpy` and the associated bug: https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

According to the bug you linked, someone recently (looks like after you left the link to the bug) left a comment that they can reliably reproduce the bug when the message size is **>=15821 bytes**.

I would recommend that you see if that also holds true for you -- i.e. can you also reproduce at that threshold -- and then evaluate if under that amount -- thus avoiding the bug documented in the issue above -- is a sufficient size for your needs. If not, you may want to try `pika` (https://github.com/pika/pika) and see if that works better with larger messages (one of the other comments on that bug suggests that `pika` did work for them with larger message sizes).

Another option that may work, depending on your exact use case, would be to include in the `rabbitmq` message `payload` a key of sorts that points allows you to fetch the large blob of data from wherever it's stored (`Postgres`, `MongoDB`, etc.) when you consume the message, and therefore allow you to avoid the bug. Perhaps not ideal if you really want to encapsulate everything inside the `payload`, but may be a feasible workaround to the bug.

In terms of debugging, since it appears that this is a bug with `rabbitpy` itself, I think you would need to debug the actual `rabbitpy` library if you wanted to proceed on that front. Doable, but perhaps not feasible due to time, etc.